# Is it possible to set a rows height in a formula in Excel?

Tags: excel-2003, excel-formula

Is it possible to set a rows height in a formula in Excel?

For Microsoft Office 2003.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so.  You would need to use VBA.

See [RowHeight property is used to get the Height](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2007/07/excel-height-of-row-rowheight-using.html) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for replying, unfortunately my users want to adjust row heights in formula's. I think you're correct, I was just wondering if someone could prove me wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use VBA. You'd have to write something into the worksheet_change event to read a particular cell then change the height based on the entry. No way to do it without coding.